# Content is not allowed trailing in this section / lambda expression are allowed at source level 1.8 or above

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

i have the next pom.xml code that i got from my university's website.And i face the problem in the next picture , i think it's all because im the pom not working properly so not including the right dependencies ( first time ever using maven and it's just a prediction) thank you in advance !  [image]

Comment: Check the project tag with this: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code.  Post the code itself as a [mcve].

Comment: First check your project tag and compare it with this: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html second create a package in `src/test/java/<packageName>/` also name the test class different like `XYZTest.java` ...

Comment: The primary error message concerns the pom.xml ("Non-parseable POM ... but got c (position ...)") - unfortunately neither that error message nor the pom.xml file is shown fully. The remaining error messages (about lambda expressions only supported on source level 1.8 and above and about the non-final local variable) are because the pom.xml cannot be read and therefore maven assumes a source level of 1.7 or below.

Comment: What @ThomasKläger says. The source level is assumed of 1.5 (Java 5) when not otherwise specified in the `pom.xml` (see also _Package Explorer_).

Comment: @kjhughes Without a screenshot, how would one know what is going on in this case?

Comment: @howlger without a screen shot the OP would / should include the complete error message ("Non-parseable POM ... but got c (position ...)") and (since the error message explicitly mentions the POM) also the complete contents of the pom.xml and then we wouldn't have to deal with a truncated error message and an incomplete excerpt from the pom.xml (because most probably the erroneous part of the pom.xml is in line 24)

Comment: @kjhughes The screenshot shows more than the code. Please ask for the missing things to add them additionally. You've been around long enough to know cases where screenshots has been removed due such comments, making the question unanswerable.

Comment: @ThomasKläger The question does not even mention an error. So with the screenshot you can ask for the missing things. The error message says there is the text `c` after `</project>` (please note that the error is dirty).

Comment: @howlger:  Your advocacy for screenshots over [mcve] with code and markup posted as text is counterproductive and contrary to site recommendations and norms.  See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/290085)

Comment: @kjhughes I'm not advocating one over the other. Please stick to the truth. Every bug report, question, etc. should tell how to reproduce the issue. In this case, only the screenshot gives information that the questioner did not even notice. I'm able to reproduce the issue with the information given by the screenshot. I wouldn't be able to reproduce the issue without the screenshot. The screenshot here tells not only the content of the `pom.xml`, but also that there is an error, the error location, the error message, the project structure, the Eclipse version and much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found somewhere that something can mess up the xml for no reason and cause a parsing problem just like i had the solution was kind of complicated for a first timer of an xml and maven dev like me , i've deleted the project and recreated a one , with a copy past of the same pom.xml code it works ! well if it does it does . that's my solution .

Answer (score 0):

In the editor, in line 23 and in the *Problems* view the **project build error `Non-parseable POM .../pom.xml: in epilog non whitespace content is not allowed but got c (position: END_TAG seen ...`** is shown.

The error means you have or had the character `c` after `</project>` causing the `pom.xml` file become unreadable for Eclipse (non-parseable because of the invalid XML). The screenshot shows that you have already removed the character but did not save the change. So it seems you **just missed** hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> **to save** the `pom.xml` containing nothing or only whitespace after `</project>`.

Comment: i'm sorry , but that's not the case at all , there was never a c and the changing was just me changing a little thing that change nothing , i saved and i still finish with the same amount of errors nothing changed :/

Comment: @BendaoudSimou The screenshot shows that there are changes that have not been saved and an error in line 23. There might also be invisible non-whitespace characters after `</project>` causing the error. Unfortunately, the screenshot shows only the cropped error message without the position (something like `(position: END_TAG seen ...</build>\r\n\r\n</project>c... @23:12)`). If this does not help, please tell the exact error message.

Comment: thank you for your effort ! you can read my answer above please it has the solution , well not a smart one , but it works ! thank you again !

Comment: @BendaoudSimou The error message in your screenshot is clear: there are characters after `</project>` which might not be visible in the editor that cause the issue. Invisible characters can happen when copying from a PDF or from HTML. You seem to have selected a little too much to copy the first time. Whatever, good to hear it's working now.

Comment: that's exactly what i've done i copied that from an html since it was from my university's website